# How do I store input dates from users into a Variable using Python?

Tags: python, variables, python-datetime

I am having some trouble trying to figure this out.  I am currently taking my Python class in college and we are currently working on functions and dates.  The instructions are: The user must enter a date separately by: year, month and day.  I have read many of the articles similar to the Python Date format, however, everything I try gives me different errors.

Here is my code so far:

```
import calendar
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

print("Enter the year: ")
year = input()

print("Enter the month: ")
month = input()

print("Enter the day: ")
day = input()

#this is where the input dates should be saved
dateEntered = 

#this is somewhat what I'm guessing the output should be
print("The date entered was: " + str(dateEntered))
```

We have covered things like:

```
now = datetime.now()
new_date = now + timedelta(days=+3)
print(new_date)
```

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to store those inputs from the user into a variable that then can be printed out.

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: why do you not want to do `dateEntered = datetime.date(year, month, day)`?

Comment: @bruno: I actually did try `dateEntered = datetime.date(year, month, day)` but I get both of these errors: if I do `day = int(input("Enter day: "))` I get descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object.  If I do `date = input()`, I get descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object.

Comment: yes you read string, just do `int(year)`etc, look my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do :

```
import datetime

print("Enter the year: ")
year = input()

print("Enter the month: ")
month = input()

print("Enter the day: ")
day = input()

dateEntered = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))

print("The date entered was:", dateEntered)
print("The date entered was:", dateEntered.strftime("%y/%m/%d"))
print("The date entered was:", dateEntered.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
print("The month entered was:", dateEntered.month)
```

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 /tmp/p.py 
Enter the year: 
2021
Enter the month: 
1
Enter the day: 
31
The date entered was: 2021-01-31
The date entered was: 21/01/31
The date entered was: 2021/01/31
The month entered was: 1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: I am still getting the same `descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object.` error.  I did word for word just as you typed it too.  I double checked my imports to ensure I got those correctly and seems so.

Comment: The code is not even getting past the `dateEntered = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))` where is giving me that error.  I even erased it and started over again and still.

Comment: @AdrianAcostaPR are you in python 3 ? I am in 3.7.5. Did you do a copy-paste of exactly  my code in a file and execute it with python 3 ?

Comment: yes.  I am actually in 3.9.1 and I did copy-paste the exact code.  I ran a repair as well.

Comment: a repair ? witch one ?

Comment: The one that comes from the Python downloader.

Comment: if I execute my code using https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ all is ok

Comment: and same on  https://www.onlinegdb.com : https://onlinegdb.com/rygaivNl_

Comment: Yes, I ran them too and they work perfectly there.  I honestly do not know what is going on with Visual Studio 2019...

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out.  I had `from datetime import datetime` and I went ahead and changed it to `import datetime` only and it seems to be working.

Comment: it is working correctly.  For some reason the professor had `from datetime import datetime` on his code and since they go over the very basic things, it might not have picked up the error on his side, but since the task goes much in details, it killed me.  Thank you!